# On a Web page - How to show a (light) image and replace it with a (heavy) one when the latter is downloaded by client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a beginner front-ender considering the following scenario :

A certain HTML page should include a heavy image (e.g - animated gif) but I don't want to force the client to sluggishly wait for it to completely download before enjoying a pretty page, rather I would prefer to show him a lightweight image (e.g - the first frame of the gif) and when the former is readily downloaded by the client's browser, replace the light one with the heavy.

What should be the best approach for the matter - Am I looking for a technological solution or a methodological one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can embed the light-weight image using a data-URL. This will show that image immediately.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,---Your-Base64-Encoded-Image-Here---" />
```

You can use [this web site](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker) to convert an image file to a data-URL.

What you then need to do is to load the larger image in the background and, once loaded, make it replace the light-weight image.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,---Your-Base64-Encoded-Image-Here---" />
<img class="heavy" src="http://server.com/path/to/heavy/weight/image.gif" />
```

The following CSS hides the heavy-weight image initially:

```
/* Don't show heavy-weight images until they're loaded */
img.heavy {
   display: none;
}
```

The following jQuery-based javascript will hide the light-weight image and show the heavy-weight image once it is loaded:

```
$(function () {
    // Register handler that will be invoked when a heavy-weight image is loaded
    $("img.heavy").on("load", function () {
        // Hide the light-weight image 
        // (we assume that it is the immediate previous 'img' sibling of the 
        //  heavy-weight image)
        $(this).prev("img").hide();

        // Show the heavy-weight image
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

---

#### Update (not using data-URL)

If you don't want to use data-URL for the light-weight image, you can use a similar approach where you don't start loading the heavy-weight image until the light-weight is loaded.

```
<img class="light" src="http://server.com/path/to/light.gif" />
<img class="heavy" data-src="http://server.com/path/to/heavy.gif" />
```

The heavy-weight image is not loaded initially because it does not have a `src`-attribute.

The following script will start loading heavy-weight images (by copying `data-src` to `src`) as soon as the light-weight image is loaded, and finally "replace" the light-weight image once the heavy-weight image is loaded.

```
$(function () {
    // Register handler that will be invoked when a light-weight image is loaded
    $("img.light").on("load", function () {
        // Start loading heavy image (by assigning the src-attribute)
        $(this).next("img.heavy").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
        }).on("load", function () {
            // Show the heavy-weight image and hide the light-weight image 
            $(this).show().prev("img.light").hide();
        });
    });
});
```

---

#### Update 2 (automatic creation of heavy-weight image element)

If you can derive heavy-weight URLs from light-weight URLs, then you can use another approach which might be easier to use and maintain.

```
<img class="light" src="img/light/image.gif" />
```

The following script will create a new heavy-weight image element for each light-weight image that is loaded. The heavy-weight image URL is copied from the light-weight image URL, but with the text `light` replaced by `heavy`.

```
$(function () {
    // Register handler that will be invoked when a light-weight image is loaded
    $("img.light").on("load", function () {
        // Create heavy-weight image element after the light-weight image
        // URL is computed from light weight image (by replacing 'light' with 'heavy')
        // The element is initially hidden.
        $("<img/>")
            .attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("light", "heavy"))
            .hide()
            .on("load", function () {
                // Show the heavy-weight image and remove the light-weight image 
                $(this).show().prev("img.light").remove();
            })
            .insertAfter(this);
    });
});
```

This version also removes the light-weight image from the DOM once the heavy-weight image is loaded.

Comment: This is a smart trick but long-winded if you have a lot of images. Maintenance would also be a pain. All those embedded images would also make your html page rather heavy; say you update some text and a much larger load of page has to be downloaded each time, where as if you stuck to images the browser would cache them until they are changed.

Comment: Yes that's a lot better I think +1. What about switching the URL of one tag rather than using two? it also could have been a change of path name e.g. `images/light/image1.jpg` to `images/heavy/image1.jpg` or change of base path https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.baseURI

Comment: @Ozzy if you have a structure to this for images it's easily automated and you can also do `.each()` on an ID like `#image-preload` and fetch from `/img/light/*`. Lazy loading is fun when you have to throw masses of data down a pipe but still want to use the page. There's also a benefit with both images being cached by the browser, so quality is higher on a page refresh once loads are finished. Only problem might be a user's cache going over a limit.

Comment: @Ozzy: I think you'll need to use two images. If you just switch the URL of a single image then the light-weight image will disappear while the heavy-weight image is being loaded - and I guess that defeat the whole purpose of having a light-weight image in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I may use another simple solution depend on a hidden iframe for the heavy image. It will replace the src of the light image when the iframe is loaded. The iframe src will be the src of the heavy image.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function replaceImg(imgId,ifrId){
    ifr = document.getElementById(ifrId);
    img = document.getElementById(imgId);
   img.src = ifr.src;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="img1" src="../img/initializing.png" />
<iframe id="ifr1" onload="replaceImg('img1','ifr1')" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400" style="display:none"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**A live DEMO [is found here](http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/wzqkH/).** However, if you could not able to notice the light image, press RUN button again in the [jsfiddle](/questions/tagged/jsfiddle) page.